# FHIR 3 - How to show a discontinued medication in MedicationAdministration

Tags: hl7-fhir

I want to show entries from the MAR.  One of the most important ones is a discontinued medication.  I am using STU 3.  I don't see anywhere that has the DC or discontinued code.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

http://hl7.org/fhir/2016Sep/medicationadministration.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what you'd like to achieve. So i assume you are searching for medicationadministrations which weren't completed regulary?

You could search for all medicationadministrations with the status stopped in that case. If you are searching for completed medicationadministrations the code would be completed.

Comment: I am trying to display entries in a MAR (Medical Administration Record).  FHIR says that you do this with the MedicalAdministration backbone element.  But I don't see how to indicate the type of record that discontinues the medication - DC

Answer (score 0):

lloyd9h - from the FHIR community answered it like this:

MedicationAdministration allows you to say what was given (or not). If you want to indicate that an overall medication has been stopped, you'll need to use MedicationOrder/MedicationRequest.

Thanks!